# MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having this weird issue while working with AWS S3. I am working on application by which I can store the images to AWS bucket. Using Multer as middleware and S3FS library to connect and upload to AWS.

But the following error pops up when I try uploading the content.

**"MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our publis
hed schema"**

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var S3FS = require('s3fs');
var upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads'
})
var S3fsImpl = new S3FS('bucket-name', {
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('profile', {
    title: 'Express'
  });
});

router.post('/testupload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
  var file = req.file;
  console.log(file);

  var path = req.file.path;
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
  console.log(stream);

  S3fsImpl.writeFile(file.name, stream).then(function () {
    fs.unlink(file.path, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    res.redirect('/profile');
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

**EDIT**
**Output:**

```
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '441_1.docx',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
  destination: 'uploads',
  filename: '662dcbe544804e4f50dfef1f52b40d22',
  path: 'uploads\\662dcbe544804e4f50dfef1f52b40d22',
  size: 13938 }
ReadStream {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 65536,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { end: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  path: 'uploads\\662dcbe544804e4f50dfef1f52b40d22',
  fd: null,
  flags: 'r',
  mode: 438,
  start: undefined,
  end: undefined,
  autoClose: true,
  pos: undefined,
  bytesRead: 0 }
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "aws-s3-images",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "hbs": "~4.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "s3fs": "^2.5.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "AWS S3 uploading images",
  "main": "app.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "keywords": [
    "javascript"
  ],
  "author": "reeversedev",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: Can you include the XML that you are uploading at Question?

Comment: Can you please tell me where can i find it? @guest271314

Comment: The problem is not with your XML but with correct setting your AWS object. Did you correctly typed your bucket name and other params ?

Comment: @ArturPoniedziałek I have updated my question. Please do check.

Comment: I think you have wrong syntax instead of var file = req.file it should be var file = req.files.file and the same with line with path. You lost "files". Can you check this and send feedback, please ?

Comment: @ArturPoniedziałek I was doing this way only before and I tried it again. It says, "Cannot read file of undefined".

Comment: Ok. I found out on stackoverflow that is  important how you build your path in AWS. Can you print out it and send here?

Comment: Yeah, I already did that. Please check Output that I've provided.

Comment: Hmm. Let's describe your full technology stack you use (all Tools, frameworks, system and versions of them all) and type of amazon account and I will try to fully reproduce your problem.

Comment: Okay, For tools and frameworks, i am attaching the package.json and for the type of amazon account is free version for 1 year as amazon S3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code should work for you. You need to remember that:
1) use unique bucket name
2) under your file object use 'originalname' instead of 'name' <-- this property does not exist

```
app.post('/testupload', function(req, res){


    var file = req.files[0];

    console.log(file.path);
    console.log(file.name);

    console.log('FIRST TEST: ' + JSON.stringify(file));

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);    

    S3fsImpl.writeFile(file.originalname, stream).then(function () 
      {
        console.log('File has been sent - OK');
      },
      function(reason)
      {
          throw reason;
      }
     ); 

     res.redirect('/index');   

});
```

Comment: Yes. I tested on Windows 7. I also created free account on AWS you did.

Comment: Can you send me your code with minimal list of files zipped into one package? I will test it on my side.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Let me upload it on Github and send it to you.

Comment: It's working right now. But can you help me retrieving the public url of the document?

Comment: Nice to here you that is started to work for you :-). Sure. I will help you to enable this url in some ours, because I need to finish some tasks.

Answer (score 21):

The S3 restricts the file deletion 1000 per DeleteObjectsRequest. Hence after fetching all KeyVersions List, I gave the check if the keys are >1000, then partition the list into sublists and then pass it to the DeleteObjectsRequest with sublists as below-

```
if (keys.size() > 1000) {
            int count = 0;
            List<List> partition = ListUtils.partition(keys, 1000);
            for (List list : partition) {
                count = count + list.size();
                DeleteObjectsRequest request = new DeleteObjectsRequest(
                        fileSystemConfiguration.getTrackingS3BucketName()).withKeys(list);
                amazonS3Client.deleteObjects(request);
                logger.info("Deleted the completed directory files " + list.size() + " from folder "
                        + eventSpecificS3bucket);
            }
            logger.info("Deleted the total directory files " + count + " from folder " + eventSpecificS3bucket);
        } else {
            DeleteObjectsRequest request = new DeleteObjectsRequest(
                    fileSystemConfiguration.getTrackingS3BucketName()).withKeys(keys);
            amazonS3Client.deleteObjects(request);
            logger.info("Deleted the completed directory files from folder " + eventSpecificS3bucket);
        }
```

Comment: Its wierd. If your DeleteObjectsRequest exceeds 1000 keys it gives this error message. **The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema.** I think there is some issue in AWS SDK code. I tried this solution and it works fine.

Answer (score 21):

I got this problem when use AmplifyJS library. Follow the document in AWS homepage about [Multipart upload overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html):

> Whenever you upload a part, Amazon S3 returns an ETag header in its
> response. For each part upload, you must record the part number and
> the ETag value. You need to include these values in the subsequent
> request to complete the multipart upload.

But S3 default config does not do it. Just go To Permissions tab  ->
Add `<ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>` into CORS Configuration.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/61

Comment: This was gold for me right here. After many hours of trying to figure out this issue, this is the final piece of the puzzle that made it work for me. Thank you so much for sharing!!!

Comment: You saved my day with this HTTP 400 issue with the s3 storage client / multipart upload. Commenting with more relevant words so that this can be found by other poor souls :-)

Answer (score 19):

So if anyone still facing this issue, in my case the issue only happens when you pass an empty array of objects you wanna delete, it causes the server to crash with the following error "MalformedXML".

```
const data: S3.DeleteObjectsRequest = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Delete: {
    Objects: [], <<---here
  },
}

return s3Bucket.deleteObjects(data).promise()
```

so just check if the array of `Objects` keys isn't equal to zero before sending that request to aws.

Comment: It was exactly my problem. I just checked if the size of `listObjects()` response is bigger than 0 and called `deleteObjects()` only if there was anything to delete. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

If you use ActiveStorage with Minio add `force_path_style: true` to your config

```
# config/storage.yml
minio:
   service: S3
   access_key_id: name
   secret_access_key: password
   endpoint: http://example.com:9000/
   region: us-east-1
   bucket: myapp-production
   force_path_style: true # add this
```

Answer (score 3):

I added the ETag in ExposeHeaders and it fixed the issue
[image]

Comment: This worked!! Saved so much time!! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
input := &s3.DeleteObjectsInput{
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Delete: &s3.Delete{Objects: objs, // <-  up to 1000 keys
       Quiet: aws.Bool(false)},
    }
```

I am using aws-sdk-go sdk, when the num of the key in objs is overer 1000,I have
get the same error like:
MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema.

The request contains a list of up to 1000 keys .
reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html

Comment: +1 for number of keys. I did not check the go code but for us in python boto3 over 1000 keys in the request caused the error. You would think they would document this is the documentation for MalformedXML on the sdk client, but you did find api documentation. We chunked the keys and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge just cross check the BUCKET NAME.

```
final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(**bucketName**, accessKeyId, is ,meta);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those which came here from talend, In my case cross check the tS3Put component's Bucket name and in the key part give any name which you want to see in the s3 as a uploaded file.

As I'm new to StackOverflow, I'm not allowed to attached images here. You can copy the below url to check it out. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1pW0.png

Answer (score -2):

Can you try this code:

```
var S3fsImpl = new S3FS('bucket-name', {
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

var fsImplStyles = S3fsImpl.getPath(file.name);

// Change us-east-1 for your region
var url = 'https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/' + fsImplStyles;
```

Send feedback, if this code works for you.

Comment: I did the same thing yesterday. When I try to submit the image to AWS, it doesn't get upload rather the key that i was using are getting deleted automatically and a new key is being created.

Comment: Why should one do so? What have you change to make it work? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it